# Type hinting a service class in a Laravel model's constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In my `Contact` model, I'm trying to type hint a service class:

```
use App\Services\ContactService;
class Contact extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var App\Services\ContactService
     */
    protected $contactService;

    public function __construct(ContactService $contactService)
    {
        $this->contactService = $contactService;
    }
}

use App\Services\CRM\CRMService;
class ContactService
{
    public function __construct(protected CRMService $crmService)
    {}
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`Too few arguments to function App\Models\Contact::__construct(), 0 passed in`

The error happens when I call `$dealer->contacts`

```
public function contacts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Contact::class, 'dealer_id');
}
```

I thought the $contactService should be injected automatically and I shouldn't be including it manually. What am I missing?

Comment: Um, what's the use case here? Why do you want to use a dependency as a parameter in the constructor? Why not define the dependency in your application and use `$this->contactService = app()->make(ServiceContractWhatever::class)` in the constructor?.

Comment: a Model's constructor takes an optional array of attributes, you can not define your own constructor with different arguments if you want the Model to function correctly as there are numerous places creating instances of models with and without an argument

Comment: As @lagbox explained, a Model recieves an optional array of data as the solely constructor parameter, so you can do `new YourModel(['name' => 'John', 'age' => 25']);` and it is initialized with those parameters. Also overriding the constructor prevents other stuff from working, like booting up and more... see the source code you are overriding: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/66b040095a5e424b8a3cf2479daa19a41f723f24/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L233-L242. In your case, you just need to store in a variable, like `$this->contactService = resolve(ContactService::class);`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and answers, I ended up changing my Contact's model constructor to this and it's working great:

```
use App\Services\ContactService;

class Contact extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contactService = app(ContactService::class);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Dealer` class

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        \App\Models\Contact::class, 
        'dealer_id'
    )->setFactory(function ($attributes) {
        return app(Contact::class, [
            'contactService' => app(ContactService::class)
        ]);
    });
}
```